# Linked-list test functions + Division by zero error

Tags: c++, constructor, linked-list, division, zero

I was supposed to create a doubly-linked list. I've also been provided with a CPP file that tests the linked-list functions (the 'test.cpp' file). The issue I'm having is that A) I don't know what my constructor and destructor are supposed to do, and B) The compiler doesn't compile the test.cpp file because it has 'division by zero' errors, when it was compiling it just fine when my List constructor was initializing the list 'head' to NULL.

Following is **the code to a node in the linked list**:

```
template <class T>
struct ListItem
{
    T value;
    ListItem<T> *next;
    ListItem<T> *prev;

    ListItem(T theVal)
    {
         this->value = theVal;
         this->next = NULL;
         this->prev = NULL;
    }
};
```

**The generic list class** is as under:

```
template <class T>
class List
{
    ListItem<T> *head;

public:

     // Constructor
     List();

    // Copy Constructor
    List(const List<T>& otherList);

    // Destructor
    ~List();

    void insertAtHead(T item);  
 };
```

Following is my present **implementation of the constructor, destructor and the insertAtHead function** (one of the functions which gets the division by zero error).

```
template <class T>
List<T>::List()
{
               head->value=0; 
}

template <class T>
List<T>::~List()
{
            ListItem<T> *temp, *temp2;
            temp=head;
                if(head->next==NULL)
                {
                                    delete head;
                }
                else
                {
                    while(temp->next!=NULL)
                    {
                                 temp=temp->next;
                                 temp2=temp->prev;
                                 delete[] temp2;
                    }
                   delete [] temp;
                   delete [] head;
                }
}


template <class T>
void List<T>::insertAtHead(T item)
{
     ListItem<T>* a = new ListItem<T>(item);

                if(head->next==NULL && head->value=0)
                {
                             head=a;
                }

                else
                {
                    head->prev=a;
                    a->next=head;
                    head=a;
                }
}
```

And finally, here's **the function that test for insertAtHead** that contains division by zero.

```
  void test_list_insert_head()
  {
       lasttotpoints = 5;

    List<int> l;
   for (int i = 0; i < 25000; i++)
    {
        l.insertAtHead(i);
        ListItem<int> *tmp = l.getHead();
        int k = i;
        while (tmp != NULL)
        {
            if (tmp->value != k)
             int a = 1/0;
             k--;
             tmp = tmp->next;
        }
    }
    cout << ".";

     lastpoints += 5;
}
```

Why is it that the compiler did not notice the division by zero before, what exactly is my constructor and destructor supposed to do?
Thanks.
PS. I know I've posted a lot of code, but I'm sort of desperate at the moment. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Why do you even have this `1/0` in your code?

Comment: Also, these are very basic questions and you have other issues in the code. I'd suggest getting a good book before using "advanced" things as templates.

Comment: I don't know, it's not my code. I'm going over it right now. I've been provided with it to test whether the function works or not. Also, it was compiling just fine when my List constructor initialized the 'head' of the list to NULL (But it ran into another error, so I changed the List constructor).

Comment: 1) "if(head->next==NULL && head->value=0)" this is always false. I think you wanted to write `if(head->next==NULL && head->value==0)` (two eq signs), isn't it ? 2) GCC complains to `1/0` as follows: `warning: division by zero`

Comment: @meh, I know the question about the constructor is a basic one. I've only worked with classes once before, and in those classes we only had integer variables (Which the constructor initialized to 0) and not pointers. I don't know what the constructor is supposed to do when a pointer is involved.

Comment: What do you expect the compiler to do when you give it an expression `1 / 0`?

Comment: 3) you wrote `head->value=0;` in c-tor, but `head` wasn't initialized before. It's UB 4) " integer variables (Which the constructor initialized to 0)" c-tor doesn't obliged to zero variables. You (!) should do it (in user-defined c-tor)

Comment: @borisbn, yes, it was supposed to be two = signs. Basically, this condition says that 'If the list is empty', i.e the node's next pointer points to NULL and contains 'value' equal 0 (I'm assuming that if the value is 0, the node is empty).

Answer (score 0):

Actually I don't understand what do you ask. I see a sort of a test, whereas in case of inconsistency the test is supposed to generate an "integer division by zero" exception or whatever applicable to the specific platform. A really perverted idea IMHO.

So, why doesn't compiler "notice" the division by zero? AFAIK it doesn't have to. Strictly speaking it may generated the code that does just this. Yes, this would generate a processor exception (interrupt) at run-time, so what? If this is the author's intent - I don't see a problem here, at least from compiler's point of view.

Are you trying to say that the compiler behaves inconsistently, sometimes allowing this to compile?

Comment: There are two questions:
A) If a class has pointers, what exactly is my constructor for that class supposed to initialize it to?
B) No, the compiler did not notice the error when my constructor was initializing the List head to NULL. But now that I've removed that line, it's started to notice that error.

Comment: @valdo - in what supposed to look like an answer you ask what the question is )